# How to reverse the exon numbers on the minus strand?

Tags: python, awk

As shown below, the exon numbers (on the 5th column) when the gene is on the minus strand ("-" on the 6th column) should be reversed. For example, for NT5C3B gene, exon numbered from 1, 2....9 should be reversed to 9, 8, ...1 , I don't know how to programmatically do this with awk or Python. I would greatly appreciate your kind help.

---

```
chr17   39968961    39969531    FKBP10  1   +
chr17   39973309    39973455    FKBP10  2   +
chr17   39974340    39974530    FKBP10  3   +
chr17   39974633    39974779    FKBP10  4   +
chr17   39975461    39975651    FKBP10  5   +
chr17   39975781    39975927    FKBP10  6   +
chr17   39976520    39976713    FKBP10  7   +
chr17   39977198    39977341    FKBP10  8   +
chr17   39977905    39978069    FKBP10  9   +
chr17   39978474    39979469    FKBP10  10  +
chr17   39981333    39981909    NT5C3B  1   -
chr17   39983677    39983878    NT5C3B  2   -
chr17   39985041    39985204    NT5C3B  3   -
chr17   39987052    39987142    NT5C3B  4   -
chr17   39988643    39988729    NT5C3B  5   -
chr17   39991321    39991368    NT5C3B  6   -
chr17   39991454    39991524    NT5C3B  7   -
chr17   39992110    39992209    NT5C3B  8   -
chr17   39992433    39992523    NT5C3B  9   -
chr17   39994042    39994378    KLHL10  1   +
chr17   39998074    39998564    KLHL10  2   +
chr17   40001377    40001995    KLHL10  3   +
chr17   40003512    40003662    KLHL10  4   +
chr17   40004184    40004599    KLHL10  5   +
chr17   40009798    40011573    KLHL11  1   -
chr17   40021078    40021629    KLHL11  2   -
chr17   40023178    40024157    ACLY    1   -
chr17   40024961    40025038    ACLY    2   -
chr17   40025295    40025378    ACLY    3   -
chr17   40025726    40025840    ACLY    4   -
chr17   40027941    40028085    ACLY    5   -
chr17   40028284    40028435    ACLY    6   -
chr17   40030063    40030218    ACLY    7   -
chr17   40034355    40034449    ACLY    8   -
chr17   40035049    40035177    ACLY    9   -
chr17   40039374    40039485    ACLY    10  -
chr17   40040445    40040527    ACLY    11  -
chr17   40042364    40042561    ACLY    12  -
chr17   40043851    40043956    ACLY    13  -
chr17   40048531    40048700    ACLY    14  -
chr17   40049285    40049427    ACLY    15  -
chr17   40052872    40052902    ACLY    16  -
chr17   40054001    40054092    ACLY    17  -
chr17   40054883    40055038    ACLY    18  -
chr17   40057948    40058066    ACLY    19  -
chr17   40060981    40061043    ACLY    20  -
chr17   40061774    40061911    ACLY    21  -
chr17   40062780    40062899    ACLY    22  -
chr17   40063694    40063825    ACLY    23  -
chr17   40065241    40065321    ACLY    24  -
chr17   40065762    40065953    ACLY    25  -
chr17   40066474    40066537    ACLY    26  -
chr17   40068672    40068795    ACLY    27  -
chr17   40069967    40070149    ACLY    28  -
chr17   40075132    40075272    ACLY    29  -
```

---

Jeff

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it's too broad. You need to show some kind of attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: AND ... do we really need 30 lines of data to illustrate the problem AND rather than a complicated verbal description, please update your Q  to show expected output from edited list of inputs. AND do all series need to be reversed or just the ones with a `-` on the last field? Good luck.

Comment: `perl -ple "s/\b([0-9])(\s+-)$/10-$1.$2/e" in.txt`. [I like Perl](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_top_10_tricks_of) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

assumes sorted input as provided file

```
awk '$4!=p{for(;i>0;i--) print a[i]; i=0; p=$4} 
   $6=="-"{a[++i]=$0; next} 1; 
       END{for(;i>0;i--) print a[i]}' file
```

For just changing the order number, easier to write a two pass algorithm, such as

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$4]=$5; next}
                   $6=="-"{$5=a[$4]-$5+1}1' file{,} | 
  column -t
```

input formatting is lost, that's why setting OFS and `column -t` for pretty printing is required.

Comment: Hi karakfa, Thanks for your kind help. Your code works but not exactly what  I want. I just want to reverse the order of the numbers on the 5th column  without affecting other fields on the same rows. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi karakfa, Thank you so much! This works great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should do pretty much what you want I think. Formatting won't be exactly the same, though.

```
from itertools import groupby                                                                       
res = []                                                                                            
with open('filenamegoeshere.whatever') as f:                                                                         
    for line in f:                                                                                  
        res.append(line.strip().split())                                                            
res2 = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(res, lambda x: (x[3], x[5]))]                                           
res3 = [l if l[0][5] == '+' else list(reversed(l)) for l in res2]                                   
res4 = [item for sublist in res3 for item in sublist]                                               
for row in res4:                                                                                    
    print(" ".join(row))
```

Comment: Hi user3030010, Thanks a lot for your kind help. Your code works but it also reversed other fields on the same rows. What I expected is that only the numbers on the 5th column is reversed. It's my fault for not defining my question clearly.